# What are best practices for choosing between property initializer vs property getter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, we have a choice between:

```
class|object X {
  [override] val y = Z
}
```

and

```
class|object X {
  [override] val y: Y
    get() = Z
}
```

Which one should be chosen and when?

Answer (score 11):

Decide based on when you want evaluation to happen. A property initializer results in memoization semantics: the initializing expression is evaluated only at instantiation time:

```
class X {
    val y = Z // Z evaluated only at instantiation time
}
```

A property getter is evaluated every time you access the property:

```
class X { 
    val y get() = Z // evaluated on every access of y
}
```

There are several factors that may make you prefer one or the other:

- If the evaluation of `Z` changes over time, you probably want to evaluate it every time.
- Even if `Z` always yields the same result, you may want to postpone the evaluation untill first access. In that case you may use a `lazy` property delegate.
- Possibly the size of the result is large and you prefer not to retain it in memory while not being actively used. In that case prefer the custom getter.

Comment: From the answer, to me it follows as a "rule of thumb":
1) If Z changes, use getter. 
2) If X is a class, use getter. 
3) If X is an object or enum or companion object, initializer can be used.
Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: My rule of thumb is to mostly use the initializer, that's the "usual" way. Use `get()` when you have a special need to use it, I mention some of them in the answer.